# DBUnit: How to refresh only on failure?

Tags: spring, junit, dbunit, spring-test

I am using DBUnit to test a Spring/Hibernate persistence.

I created an abstract test:

```
public abstract class AbstractTestCase extends
    AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests {

    @Override
    protected String[] getConfigLocations() {
        return new String[] { 
                "classpath:/applicationContext.xml",
                "classpath:/testDataSource.xml" };
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSetUpInTransaction() throws Exception {
        DataSource dataSource = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
        Connection con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);

        boolean validateSchemaExists = true;
        IDatabaseConnection dbUnitCon = new DatabaseConnection(con,
                "MHADB_TEST", validateSchemaExists);

        DatabaseConfig dbUnitConConfig = dbUnitCon.getConfig();
        dbUnitConConfig.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY,
                new OracleDataTypeFactory());

        boolean enableColumnSensing = true;
        boolean enableDTDMetadata = false;
        IDataSet dataSet = new FlatXmlDataSet(new File(
                "./src/test/resources/mhadb-dataset.xml"),
                enableDTDMetadata,
                enableColumnSensing);
        try {
            DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(dbUnitCon, dataSet);
        } finally {
            DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, dataSource);
        }
    }
}
```

But whenever I run a test, it refresh the DB agains the dataSet before EVERY test method, which is quite very long and very not nice I think.

How could I reload/refresh only on failure?

P.S.: How much does the code suck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to speed up the tests, even thought the behaviour is still not as expected (refresh on fail):

```
    dbUnitConConfig.setFeature(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_BATCHED_STATEMENTS,
            true);
```